# starting a bat script from bash under windows

Tags: windows, bash, batch-file

I am trying to start a .bat file from [gow](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) bash. I can sucessfully start a batch and return to bash with the following (I am in `C:\tmp\a\` directory), the content of the file `a.bat` file consists a single command `cd` (to print the current working directory):

```
$ cat a.bat
cd

$ cmd "/C a.bat"

c:\tmp\a>cd
c:\tmp\a
$
```

Now if I try to start the program from `c:\tmp` (one level higher in the hierarchy of directory structure), I get an error:

```
$ cmd "/C a\\a.bat"
'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

$ cmd '/C a\a.bat'
'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

$ cmd '/C a/a.bat'
'a' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I start a batch script given a path to it, and return to bash?

Comment: You probably could change the working directory of the shell to the directory of the script. (I assume that `cmd` inherits the working directory.) Or give the full path instead.

Comment: yes, I thought about that too. The issue is, that that script starts another bunch of scripts, and all parameters needs to be readjusted (as these scripts input other files from other directories as well

Comment: You can "temporarily" change the working directory using a subshell, i.e. `(cd a; cmd 'a.bat')`.

Comment: Why are you quoting the entire parameter list? Have you tried `cmd /c a\a.bat' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found a very simple solution:
Add a dot before /C

```
cmd ". /C a\a.cmd"
```

After that gow (and cygwin and alikes) stop treating the argument as containing paths and converting it to POSIX paths.
And cmd ignores everything up to /C (well, almost everything, I think).

**a.cmd**:

```
@echo off
echo it's working
```

**output**:

```
bash-3.1$ cmd ". /C a\a.cmd"
it's working
bash-3.1$
```

**[Update]**

After some research I found that [POSIX path conversion](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Posix_path_conversion) has a very clean description of conversion rules.
In your case the rule `An argument with a leading / is converted up to the first /..` seems to be applied.
Conversion results in changing '\' to '/'. So, you get `a/a.cmd`, that is `a` with a switch `/a.cmd`. And this results in the observed error, of course.

The link above addresses MSYS and seems to be a bit outdated, but I've checked some of the rules in bash from my fresh Git for Windows installation (based on MSYS2), and they look working as described.

Comment: this is an impressive piece of advice. Nice work indeed. Can you also share the url that adding a dot at the beginning of the command helps to convert (or not convert) some of the arguments into POSIX paths? Any additional urls to guide systematic understanding of the issue would be very helpful!

Comment: @arthur, I've updated my answer, I hope this will help.

Comment: impressive piece of knowledge. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research and posting questions to other forums I found the following additional info to run the job "correctly":

```
cmd //D . //C "a\a.cmd"
```

References:

- [Github issue #244, Unix to Windows path translation may corrupt command switches/arguments](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/issues/244)
- [Github issue #243, when bash starts a cmd, it adds a buggy double quote symbol at the end of the line](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/issues/243)